# How to put together multiple Maps <Character, Set<String>> without overriding Sets

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, merge, set

In my project I am using two maps `Map<Character, Set<String>>.`

```
map1 - is temporally holding needed values
map2 - is summing all data from map1 after each loop
```

for example i got:

```
map2 = (B; Beryllium, Boron, Bromine)
map2 = (H; Hellum, Hydrogen, Hafnium)
```

now new map1 is:

```
map1 = (B; Bismuth)
map1 = (O; Oxygen)
```

In my code adding Oxygen as new entry is ok, but adding new entry for B ends by overraidding existing data in values and leave me only Bismuth.

My code:

```java
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   Set<String> words = new TreeSet<>();
   String word = iterator.next();
   char[] wordChars = word.toCharArray();

//some code

   words.add(word);
   map1.put(wordChars[i], words);

}
map2.putAll(map1);
```

I tought about using .merge but I have no idea how to use it with Sets as values, and I cannot use simple Strings with concat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Map#merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) like this:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map1; // [key="B";values=["Beryllium", "Boron", "Bromine"]]
Map<String, Set<String>> map2; // [key="B";values=["Bismuth"] key="I";values=["Iron"]]

for (Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
   map1.merge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), (s1, s2) -> {s1.addAll(s2); return s1;});
}

//map1 = [key="B";values=["Beryllium", "Boron", "Bromine", "Bismuth"] key="I";values=["Iron"]]
```

Comment: Set::addAll gives me error: Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert boolean to java.util.Set

Answer (score 1):

[`Map::compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) is probably what you're looking for.  This gives you a way to map any existing value (if there is one), or provide one if not.

For example, in your case something like the following would probably suffice:

```
oldMap.compute("B", current -> {
    if (current == null) {
        // No existing entry, so use newMap's one
        return newMap.get("B");
    } else {
        // There was an existing value, so combine the Sets
        final Set<String> newValue = new HashSet<>(current);
        newValue.addAll(newMap.get("B"));
        return newValue;
    }
});
```

There's also [`MultiValueMap`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html) and [`Multimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from spring and guava respectively (if you're ok bringing in dependencies) which cover this case with less work already.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary map1 will not be needed in this case. Get the set for that character, if null create a new set. Add the word to that set and put in the map:

```
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   String word = iterator.next();

   //some code 
   Set<String> words = map2.get(word.charAt(0));
   if(words == null) {
     words = new TreeSet<>();
   }
   words.add(word);
   map2.put(word.charAt(0), words);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the merge() function, if the specified key is not already associated with a value or the value is null, it associates the key with the given value.
Otherwise, i.e if the key is associated with a value, it replaces the value with the results of the given remapping function. So in order to do not overwrite the old value you must write your remapping function so that it combines the old and new values.

To do so replace this line :

```
map2.putAll(map1);
```

with

```
map1.forEach( (key, value)->{
        map2.merge(key, value, (value1,value2) -> Stream.of(value1,value2)
                                                        .flatMap(Set::stream)
                                                        .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    });
```

This will iterate over map1 and add echh key which is not present into map2 and associate it with the given value and for each key which is already present it combines the old values and new values.

Alternative you can also work with `Map.computeIfPresent` and `Map.putIfAbsent`

```
map1.forEach( (key, value)->{
        map2.computeIfPresent(key, (k,v) -> Stream.of(v,value).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        map2.putIfAbsent(key, value);
    });
```